# What's the size of this "mini" video?

Tags: youtube, images, thumbnail

I want to know the size of YouTube's mini videos in pixels. i.e. the videos that show up usually at the end of a YouTube video by the owner of the channel. e.g.

[image]

I want the exact size of that small video in the image in relation to 1920x1080 pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution is dynamic so in relation to 1920×1080 px fullscreen the image is of a size **620×349** px.

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Comment: Jazak Allah khayran